# Why am I getting a NameError?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
from crypt import crypt
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_letters, digits

def decrypt(all_hashes, salt, charset=ascii_letters + digits + "-"):
     products = (product(charset, repeat=r) for r in range(8))
     chain = itertools.chain.from_iterable(products)
     for candidate in chain:
         hash = crypt(candidate, salt)
         if hash in all_hashes:
              yield candidate, hash
              all_hashes.remove(hash)
              if not all_hashes:
                 return

all_hashes = ['aaRrt6qwqR7xk', 'aaacT.VSMxhms' , 'aaWIa93yJI9kU',
'aakf8kFpfzD5E', 'aaMOPiDnXYTPE', 'aaz71s8a0SSbU', 'aa6SXFxZJrI7E'
'aa9hi/efJu5P.', 'aaBWpr07X4LDE', 'aaqwyFUsGMNrQ', 'aa.lUgfbPGANY'
'aaHgyDUxJGPl6', 'aaTuBoxlxtjeg', 'aaluQSsvEIrDs', 'aajuaeRAx9C9g'
'aat0FraNnWA4g', 'aaya6nAGIGcYo', 'aaya6nAGIGcYo', 'aawmOHEectP/g'
'aazpGZ/jXGDhw', 'aadc1hd1Uxlz.', 'aabx55R4tiWwQ', 'aaOhLry1KgN3.'
'aaGO0MNkEn0JA', 'aaGxcBxfr5rgM', 'aa2voaxqfsKQA', 'aahdDVXRTugPc'
'aaaLf47tEydKM', 'aawZuilJMRO.w', 'aayxG5tSZJJHc', 'aaPXxZDcwBKgo'
'aaZroUk7y0Nao', 'aaZo046pM1vmY', 'aa5Be/kKhzh.o', 'aa0lJMaclo592'
'aaY5SpAiLEJj6', 'aa..CW12pQtCE', 'aamVYXdd9MlOI', 'aajCM.48K40M.'
'aa1iXl.B1Zjb2', 'aapG.//419wZU']


all_hashes = set(all_hashes)
salt = 'aa'
for candidate, hash in decrypt(all_hashes, salt):
     print 'Found', hash, '! The original string was', candidate
```

And when I go to run it i get the following traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in decrypt
NameError: global name 'itertools' is not defined
```

And can not figure out why it is happening.

Someone please shed some light, thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have an indentation error in the code you posted.  (the imports are indented when they shouldn't be)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't look like you imported `itertools`...

```
from itertools import product
```

doesn't count as that will only pull `product` directly into your module's namespace (your module still doesn't know anything about the rest of `itertools`.  Just add:

```
import itertools
```

at the top of your script and that error should go away because now you've pulled the `itertools` namespace into your module's namespace under the name `itertools`.  In other words, to have access to the `chain` function, you'd use `itertools.chain` (as you have in your script above).

Comment: when I do that it says the same but about "product"

Comment: You can have both at the top:  `import itertools` and `from itertools import product`.  but, you'd probably want to use 1 or the other.  in this case, you'd change `product` to `itertools.product` if you only do `import itertools`.

Answer (score 4):

You want either:

```
from itertools import chain, product
```

and use `chain` and `product`, or:

```
import itertools
```

and use `itertools.chain` and `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

from itertools import izip_longest
```

This helped me use `itertools` and then be able to use `izip_longest` for iterating through uneven length of arrays.